# Add JPanel to frame using if statement

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I'm trying to add a JPanel to my Frame on the click of a JMenuItem.
I've looked in past posts and I've tried it using:

```
getContentPane().add(myJPanel)
revalidate();
repaint();
```

To no avail.
My Game class is just simply a constructor with the size set and a background colour for now.
Oh and sorry for the messy code, I had deleted my non working original and done this up quickly to give an idea of what I've tried.
Any Suggestions will be appreciated.

```
package game;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame{

static boolean gameActive = false;
Game game;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu file;
JMenuItem startGame;
JMenuItem checkScore;
JMenuItem closeGame;
int userScore;

public Main() {

    game = new Game();
    gameActive = false;

    //set JMenuBar
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    file = new JMenu("File");
    startGame = new JMenuItem("Start Game");
    checkScore = new JMenuItem("Check Score");
    closeGame = new JMenuItem("Close Game");
    menuBar.add(file);
    file.add(startGame);
    file.add(checkScore);
    file.add(closeGame);

    startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gameActive = true;
        }

    });

    if(gameActive == true){
        getContentPane().add(game);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    checkScore.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(checkScore, "your Score is " + userScore);

        }

    });

    closeGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //JFrame Properties
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("BattleGrounds");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

}



   public static void main(String[] args){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
                    new Main();
           }
       });
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your statements *inside* your `ActionListener` rather than having them in the constructor:

```
startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        gameActive = true;
        add(game);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Notice the `gameActive` check is redundant for the current code. Also `getContentPane().add(game)` can simply be written as `add(game)`.

Note that [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is purposely designed to manage this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the `if` block will never be executed because `gameActive` is false when the constructor is called

```
 if(gameActive == true){
    getContentPane().add(game);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

You need to show your game activity when the `startGame` is clicked; **however** you have to check that the `game` is not added to your `contentPane` already so when the user click the menu many times it does not add a new `game` instance everytime

```
startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       gameActive = true;
       if(game == null) {
          game = new Game(); // remove the game creation from the constructor
          getContentPane().add(game);           
       }
    }

});
```